# How do I add pushpins to a ClusterLayer for Bing Map in web API?

Tags: bing-maps

The ClusterLayer constructor works fine but I want to change what pins are on the ClusterLayer later in the code. setPushpins() seems like the desired function here but I am getting an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_v8Map' of undefined. This is a sample of what I have so far

```
    window.map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map("#map_canvas",
                {credentials:maps_key,
                    enableSearchLogo:false,
                    showCopyright:false,
                    mapTypeId:Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road,
                    zoom:4,
                    scrollwheel:true,
                    center:new Microsoft.Maps.Location(us_latitude, us_longitude)
                });

Microsoft.Maps.loadModule("Microsoft.Maps.Clustering", function(){

    //Generate 1,000 random pushpins in the map view.
    //var pins = Microsoft.Maps.TestDataGenerator.getPushpins(1000, map.getBounds());
    var pins = [];

    var latitude = 43;
    var longitude = -120;

    var loc = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(latitude, longitude);
    pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(loc);
    pins.push(pin);
    //Create a ClusterLayer and add it to the map.

    var loc = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(latitude+10, longitude+10);
    pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(loc, options);
    pins.push(pin);

    var clusterLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.ClusterLayer(pins);
    map.layers.insert(clusterLayer);

    clusterLayer.setPushpins(pins);


});
```

How should I go about changing which pins are part of a ClusterLayer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing the setPushpins function I do see the error you are seeing. Interestingly after ignoring the error message the clusteringLayer adds the pushpins and works fine. I'll have the team look into why this error is being thrown.

Comment: ++rbrundritt
This is the link to a question i asked related to bing maps v8. Please see if you can help. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396300/identifying-pushpins-after-plotting-them-bingmaps

Comment: Was this error found/resolved? We are still having troubles of adding pushpins later. Calling this function results in nothing being added.

Comment: Ah no worries found the issue. Was a stupid mistake a different method was clearing the layers.